# Parameters.Addwithvalue with spaces

Tags: c#, sql

I feel like this is really simple but after googling for days I cant figure it out.

I'm trying to select from an SQL DB, and use variables in the select statement.
But `Parameters.Addwithvalue();` won't work for a table column that has a space in it.
In SQL i need to add [] but it won't work in C#.

This for example does work, as it should, pretty straight forward

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"fullName", string.Format("{0}", "%" + userName.TrimStart() + "%"));
```

But this won't work

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"glboal_country_Travel", string.Format("{0}{1}", "[" + glboal_country.TrimStart(), " Travel]"));
```

I have tried diffrent variations but nothing works, nor does `Parameters.Add(...)`
and no i can't change the DB column names for

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Full SQL command

```
@"select [AD ID], DISPLAYNAME, Categorisation, @glboal_country from [...db].[dbo].[...View] where [AD ID] = @AD_ID or DISPLAYNAME like @fullName"
```

Comment: Hi @TheITGuy, can you attach the complete SQLCommand and also possibly the sample database records as you mentioned. Thank you.

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: (SQL) Identifiers cannot be passed as parameters. Parameters are for values (literals). And as a side note: ["AddWithValue is Evil"](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: @YongShun I updated the full sql command, and the records or simple records, moistly nvarchar

Comment: @TheMixy that's the things, I don't get an error just that column doesn't come back, I do get Display name, AD ID etc just not global_country

Comment: TheITGuys, may I know reason why you set `@glboal_country` param in `SELECT` statement. And your `glboal_country_Travel` in SQLCommand Parameter is not matched with `@glboal_country` in SQL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server LIKE containing bracket characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661125/sql-server-like-containing-bracket-characters)

Comment: @Charlieface No. for some reason that only works in the second part of the query 
```...where @pram like @param```, not in the ```select @column``` name part.

Comment: When you say "doesn't work" what happens?

Comment: I get an error that it's an invalid column, but i get the error when trying to display it not when executing the SQL query

Comment: Its hard to help if you dont share exact error messages. Also where and how are you trying to "display it"?

Comment: @TheMixy I'm not really getting an error message. I am trying to fill a DataTable and instead of filling the results from the DB i get the variable instead. so I get all of the results back but the ```@glboal_country``` gives me the variable, that variable is column name in the DB which can change depending on selections. I get an error when trying to display it, the error is that the column doesn't exist in the DataTable which makes sense so the issue is with filling the DataTable.

Comment: Aha, I dont think you can do it this way. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30454747/how-to-set-a-column-name-in-sql-query-as-parameter#30455085

Comment: @TheMixy the only other way i found it to work it like           ```new SqlCommand(string.Format(@"select  [AD ID], DISPLAYNAME, {0} Labor]
from [DB].[dbo].[View] where [AD ID] = @param1 or DISPLAYNAME like @Param2", "[" + glboal_country.TrimStart())))```               from a security point of view, is this okay?

Comment: Concatenating sql commands is not good practice because of potential sql injection. But, in your case it depends on who provides the variable for {0}. If it's provided directly by user input, you could have security problems... the only alternative is then to restructure your table (which I would do)

Comment: In my case the it's a dropdown selection by the user